# 'by' seems to not retain attribute of 'date' type columns in data.table, possible bug

Tags: r, data.table, type-mismatch

I have data.table named data like this:

```
> head(data)

    start        end     unit
1: 2008-11-17 2007-01-23 ADM 2-05
2: 2008-12-29 2007-01-06 BOB 4-07
3: 2008-12-31 2007-01-01 DAT15-02
4: 2008-12-31 2010-01-01 DAT15-06
5: 2008-12-31 2010-01-02 TUW 4-09
6: 2008-12-31 2010-01-02 BEG 5-01
```

With data types as follows:

```
sapply(dane, class)
start         end        unit 
"Date"      "Date" "character"
```

I'm trying to debug this line:

```
data[,
    list(date = format(seq(from = start, to = end, by = "1 day"), "%Y-%m-%d")), 
    by = list(start, end, unit)
]
```

Then I get error message:

```
Error in del/by : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I figured out, that the error is caused by conversion to numeric which takes place when I pass something as argument to the list in 'by'.

So this modified code works:

```
dane[,
    list(date = format(seq(
       from = as.Date(start, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
       to = as.Date(end, origin = "1970-01-01"), by = "1 day"), 
       "%Y-%m-%d")), 
    by = list(start, end, unit)
]
```

This looks like a bug in data.table package. I wonder if anybody knows about this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that this bug has been reported: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5437&group_id=240&atid=975

Answer (score 0):

#### This is now fixed in [commit #1256](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=1256) of v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=1257):

> o  Using `by` columns with attributes (ex: `factor`, `Date`) in `j` did not retain the attributes, also in case of `:=`. This was partially a regression from an earlier fix (`bug #2531`) due to recent changes for R3.1.0. Now fixed and clearer tests added. Thanks to Christophe Dervieux for reporting and to AdamB for reporting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536586/by-seems-to-not-retain-attribute-of-date-type-columns-in-data-table-possibl) on SO. Closes `#5437`.

Thanks again for reporting.